# How do I run UnitTest in a WASM runtime

Tags: c#, blazor, webassembly

I'm writing several libraries that are cross-platform and I eventually plan on running in WASM on a Blazor app. However, all the unit tests run in normal .NET and just mock out the JS runtime. I want to make sure during the execution of my code that it's never executing some operation that won't work in WASM. How do I go about running tests like this, preferably in some way that will work with GitHub Actions?

Comment: In what engine do you need your WASM to run? Not an answer to your question, but (as I understand), you're worried that the Blazor --> WASM compiler has a bug to produce unexecutable code; I think in this case compatibility between produced WASM and the engine running it is more important...

Answer (score 0):

If you are specifically testing for WASM/UI functionality, what's wrong with Selenium UI tests? I personally use these on my Blazor projects and it works great for verifying all user-facing functionality.

Here's a random guide (not mine) on running Selenium with GitHub Actions: https://www.lambdatest.com/blog/selenium-github-actions-example/